# How do I multiply two inputs from the user (console)?

Tags: c#

I have this code to read the user input.

```
Console.WriteLine(userName + " How many hours did you work in the last two weeks");
string hrsWrkd = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("You worked:" + hrsWrkd + "hrs");
Console.WriteLine(userName + "Your Gross paycheck is ");
string grossPay = (hourlyRate*hrsWrkd);
Console.WriteLine();
```

I want to multiply those values:

```
string grossPay = (hourlyRate*hrsWrkd);
```

I am new to programming and need help to understand what is wrong and how can I do it properly.

Comment: Ummm... like that? What is wrong with the code you wrote?

Comment: They are both inputs and it depends on what the user typed

Comment: Console.WriteLine(userName + " How many hours did you work in the last two weeks");
            string hrsWrkd = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You worked:" + hrsWrkd + "hrs");

            Console.WriteLine(userName + "Your Gross paycheck is ");
            string grossPay = (hourlyRate*hrsWrkd);
            Console.WriteLine();

Comment: You need to use numbers, not strings. Look into the `Parse` and `TryParse` family of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the string so that you get a number, then you can use that in a calculation. The result is also a number, so you need to convert it if you want it as a string. Example:

```
int hours = Int32.Parse(hrsWrkd);
string grossPay = (hourlyRate * hours).ToString();
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine(userName + "Your Gross paycheck is ");
            int hours = Int32.Parse(hrsWrkd);
            int rate = Int32.Parse(hourlyRate);
            string grossPay = (rate * hours).ToString();
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.ReadLine();   this does not display total paycheck

Comment: @WilliamGood: You still have to input the data into the strings before parsing the strings.

Comment: @WilliamGood: You already did that in the original code: `string hrsWrkd = Console.ReadLine();`

Answer (score 0):

Use double instead of string. String cant do math.

```
double grossPay = hourlyRate * hrsWrkd;
```

Comment: Read his title buddy. "string grossPay = (hourlyRate*hrsWrkd);" the type is there as string.

Comment: Okay, that title *really* needs some work. I see what you saw though. Even so, he is currently trying to multiply two strings, which still wouldn't work (that one you obviously didn't know).

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't include what *type* the variables are.  Assuming they are `double`, `decimal` or `float` then your code will work.
e.g.

```
double hourlyRate = 20.25, hrsWrkd = 10.5;
double grossPay = (hourlyRate*hrsWrkd);
Console.WriteLine(grossPay);
```

Comment: The user enters the hourly rate and hours worked so how would I do this

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this...

```
grossPay = Convert.ToString((hourlyRate*hrsWrkd));
```

This will perform the calculation then convert the answer to a string, and store the value into grossPay.

Just make sure hourlyRate and hrsWrked are declared as double varibles.

Comment: Ok how do I convert them as double variables?

Answer (score 0):

When you read the input from a console application you use

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

This method however only returns a value with the type [`String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx).

The type `String` is only used for text content. If you have to deal with numbers and perform mathematical operations you have to use [a type that handle numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).

As mentioned, you can use the method `Parse` or `TryParse` of a numeric type to convert your `string` into a numeric type.

```
double numericValue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Using the above example you will read text from the console and convert it to a value of type `double` using the [`Double.Parse` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx).

Once you have all the variables in a numeric type you can multiply them:

```
double hourlyRate = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double hrsWrkd = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double grossPay = hourlyRate * hrsWrkd;
```